No output in a solution for Euler Problem 4
The problem states:
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two
-digit numbers.
import math


def palin_check(n):
    n_1 = n
    x = 1
    ori_len = len(str(n))
    y = len(str(n)) - 1
    m = 0

    while x <= ori_len:
        m = m + (n % 10)*(math.pow(10, y))
        n //= 10  # Use integer division instead of floating-point division
        x += 1
        y -= 1

    if m % 10 == 0:
        is_palin = False
    elif m == n_1:
        is_palin = True
    else:
        is_palin = False

    print(is_palin)
    return is_palin


def largest_palin_prod(n):
    x = math.pow(10, n+1)-1
    y = math.pow(10, n+1)-1

    while x >= 0:
        while y >= 0:
            if palin_check(x * y):
                print(x*y, "is the greatest palindrome product of", n, "digit numbers.")
                exit()
            else:
                y -= 1
        x -= 1


largest_palin_prod(int(input("Enter the number of digits for the largest palindrome product: ")))


This is my attempt at the problem in Python. I guess it can be more concise, but i find this more straightforward. I don't think there are any issues in the code, and it even ran successfully, however gave no output. I tried it on other IDEs too, but its the same. Also I am aware of the similar questions posted, but why this code is incorrect is bugging me and not the system.

Are you really using Python 2.7? If so, why? It is unsupported now and you should be using Python 3.x.

I don't know if your code is correct or not, but your Code does give output and it is really high number of lines since it has
    while x <= ori_len:
    m = m + (n % 10)*(math.pow(10, y))
    n //= 10  # Use integer division instead of floating-point division
    x += 1
    y -= 1

if m % 10 == 0:
    is_palin = False
elif m == n_1:
    is_palin = True
else:
    is_palin = False

print(is_palin)

this code.
I used Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.
Runned it on python IDLE Shell 3.11.4
Here's the part of the output I got
output
Ultimately it leads to a IDLE not responding situation.
IDLE Not Responding
Try python IDLE Shell.

The problem is in these lines:
    x = math.pow(10, n+1)-1
    y = math.pow(10, n+1)-1

These lines calculate x and y as floats, so the values you pass in to palin_check will also be floats.
However your palin_check function assumes that the value passed in as n will be an int. If, say, n is the float value 9801.0, then len(str(n)) will be 6, despite 9801 having only 4 digits. If you convert a float to a string, you will get a trailing .0 if the float value happens to be an integer.
Converting x and y to ints will sort that problem out:
    x = int(math.pow(10, n+1)-1)
    y = int(math.pow(10, n+1)-1)

I made that change to your code and I got some output from it.
However, you might also want to consider the following points:

Do the lines above calculate x and y with the correct length?
The largest palindrome product of 3-digit numbers is 906609 = 993 × 913. Does your code give the correct answer for this case?


the int thing helped get my output, but I still have 2 questions:
Do the lines above calculate x and y with the correct length? (wdym?), and
I realized that if I calculate all the products of x as 999 with y, I and I need not do the same thing with 998's all products. is that causing the program to get a wrong output. the output it is giving is 99000099. that is way larger than 906609.

@AyushSingh: if you enter 3 as the number of digits, do the lines above calculate x and y as 3 digits long? print out x and y and see if they are as you expect.  (They weren't as I expected, and you can't make 99000099 from multiplying together two three-digit numbers.)  Your code doesn't always find the largest palindromic product because it would find one from multiplying 999 and a small number before it finds one with two numbers both below 999 but fairly close to it.

When you print out the largest palindromic product, try printing out the values of x and y as well.

i see, thanks. its a major logic problem too.
